# Identify primary key candidates through SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have a raw data with millions of rows and no constraints and I want to identify unique columns for primary keys through SQL code.

Is there any way we can identify primary key candidates through SQL code?

Comment: Do you mean select a column to use as the primary key?  If so, you've got to find a column that is unique

Comment: By 'identify primary key' I presume you mean identify a unique column to use as the primary key?

Comment: ? Find a column or set of columns such that `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` is the same as `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT candidatekey(s)) FROM` ... its going to take a few table scans though?

Comment: What about compound keys? `;-)`

Comment: @StuartLC, I think it is a good point but if we have multiple columns say more than 50, results a multiple table scan.

Comment: SSIS has "Candidate Key Profile" as part of the [Data Profiling Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895263.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You could try the following queries

```
select count(<potential_column>),count(distinct <potential column>) from <table>
```

When the counts match, you have a candidate key for consideration.

For example, if I had a table of people called PEOPLE, I might do something like.

```
select 'FullName' as FldName, count(fullname) as Tot,count(distinct fullName) as TotD 
from People
union
select 'SSN' as FldName, count(SSN) as Tot,count(distinct SSN) as TotD 
from People
```

This would return two rows, showing the field name and counts.  Any row where **tot** matches **totd** would be a candidate, although in this example, I'd rely on SSN (Social Security number) based on knowledge of the data.

You could run the same query using concatenated fields, such as

```
  select 'First/Last' as FldName, count(Firstname+lastName) as Tot,
          count(distinct firstname+LastName) as TotD 
    from People
```

if you are looking for compound keys, although trying to decide which fields to concatenate would require a better understanding of your data

Comment: can you provide example for the same with some table name. It will be a value add

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to produce a list of unique columns for a table:

```
DECLARE
     @TableSchema sysname = 'dbo'
    ,@TableName sysname = 'Task'
    ,@ColumnName sysname=''
    ,@sql nvarchar(max)=''
;
---
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR (SELECT [COLUMN_NAME] FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] WHERE [TABLE_SCHEMA] = @TableSchema AND [TABLE_NAME] = @TableName);
OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ColumnName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @sql += 'SELECT '''+@ColumnName+''' FROM '+QUOTENAME(@TableSchema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+' HAVING COUNT(*)=COUNT(DISTINCT '+QUOTENAME(@ColumnName)+')';
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ColumnName;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 SET @sql += 'UNION ALL ';
END;
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
---
```

This is not necessarily the best way to choose your primary key though unless you can guarantee the column won't have duplicates in the future.  This code can be useful however when analysing datasets to discover which columns tend to contain unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible (as per answers and comments) to detect whether permutations of **existing** data in a table is unique or not, at any point where it isn't clear that there is an obvious natural or existing surrogate key in a table, instead of trying to create a `pseudo primary key` out of one or more aribtrary columns in the data by guessing or deducing uniqueness from the data, I would instead create a new surrogate primary key, e.g. an `IDENTITY` integer, or a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

**Rationale**

- We have designed it to be unique, rather than hoping that it will continue to be unique. For example, Datetime / Timestamps have a nasty habit of not being unique.
- We will name the column appropriately so that others will immediately recognize it as a Primary Key
- It is likely to be narrower than a composite key made of other random columns

Comment: This is what I'd usually always do when designing a table where I need a unique identifier and one can't be easily identified within the data

Comment: Definitely agree, a surrogate makes a lot of sense unless there is a very clear candidate for primary key, and even then, I would still consider a surrogate key.

Answer (score 1):

If a table has 10 non-nullable columns then it has 1024 possible sets of attributes (= power set) any of which might be keys. Would you really want to test all of them?

The only prudent and reliable way to determine keys is from first principles: analysis of your business requirements based on an understanding of what the data is supposed to represent. In the absence of that analysis and understanding how would you know whether your data is a reliable, accurate sample from which to infer suitable keys? If the table hasn't had any key constraints enforced on it in the past then maybe it already contains erroneously duplicated data.

Comment: Sensible answer. When the question is "How do I shoot myself in the foot?" the right answer is not "Step 1: load the weapon..."

Answer (score 0):

How about using sp_special_columns to find uniqueness? It looks (from Googling) that this sproc is designed to find uniqueness, MSFT definition of sp_special_columns: "Returns the optimal set of columns that uniquely identify a row in the table. Also returns columns automatically updated when any value in the row is updated by a transaction."